# Empty object being used as an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and learning. 
I see some code where variable is declared as `abcBean={};`

and then being used as

```
abcBean[SOME_SET.KEY] = false
```

Can someone please explain how an empty object is being used as an array?

Comment: `[]` sets properties by name. Array indexes are one kind of property, but they’re not the only kind of property. `abcBean.x` is equivalent to `abcBean['x']`, for example. I think this is probably a duplicate of something.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I work on Microsoft's Chakra JavaScript engine)

In JavaScript, all objects are prototype instances and their properties are defined at runtime. They can be accessed using dot-syntax (`object.property`) but also by name (`object['property']`) which enables some interesting meta-programming scenarios.

Internally (inside a JavaScript engine) JavaScript prototype objects are typically implemented as a kind of dictionary or hashtable. You can also use `Number` instances as keys too, not just names, which has the interesting effect of a JavaScript object exhibting a kind of duality where it is both an array (indexed by integer offset) as well as a dictionary (indexed by integer key).

For example, these four objects can be considered equivalent:

```
var array1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var array2 = new Array( 1, 2, 3 );
var dict1 = { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3 };

function Constructor() { this[0] = 1; this[1] = 2; this[2] = 3; }
var dict2 = new Constructor();
```

In practice, engines have optimizations where JavaScript arrays and objects are handled differently based on their initialization syntax. Internally in Chakra the `array1` and `array2` objects will be represented as an array of integers but `dict1` and `dict2` will both be hashtable objects, however if you add a non-integer element to `array1` or `array2`, or add an element by key, then Chakra will (behind the scenes) re-represent the object internally as a hashtable (or some other more appropriate representation).

Of note, this will *not* internally expand `array1` to an 101-element-sized array:

```
var array1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
array[100] = 5;
```